# Licensing check from second app

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have an trial application which holds the hole logic of the app and I have a pay app, which is only an unlocker app. While starting the trial app I check if the pay app is installed and it will show the pay app content, otherwise it shows the trial content. (In my situation I don't like the user to start the pay app.)

Now I would like to add the licencing-mechanism for my special situation and now my question: Is it possible to check if the pay app is licensed from (inside) my trial app, which will be started first? (I know how to do it with checking the own app. only one app)

Does anyone have a hint or concept for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either provide an IntentFilter in the paid app, which returns a pre-defined value to the caller indicating whether or not it's licensed, or you could turn your paid app into a ContentProvider, which is more elegant.